# Xcode not recognising new outlet and action connections

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have recently been experiencing a problem with Xcode 7 & (8 Beta) that when I try to add a new outlet or action connection I get this problem below, stating that Xcode could not find any information relating to that certain view controller. I have tried numerous steps to try to fix this problem but found none that actually fully solve my problem.

[image: enter image descripton here]

I had tried the following solutions:

- Deleting Xcode's Derived Data
- Deleting and reinstalling Xcode
- Cleaning my project
- Creating a new project and transferring the existing project into the new one
- Programmatically creating an action or outlet
- Removing the class name from the storyboard and creating a new one or placing the class name back into the storyboard
- Force quitting Xcode and restarting my machine
- And probably more!

Below I have posted my solution to this bug/problem.

Note: This solution is for Xcode 6 onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the above bug follow these simple steps:

Note: Before starting this process I recommend that you fully backup your projects. I believe nothing will happen to your projects but it's worth taking the precaution.

**Step 1**

Force quit Xcode and open Finder

**Step 2**

In Finder press `cmd` + `shif` + `g`

**Step 3**

Enter `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/` and delete the `DerivedData` folder (Make sure you empty your Trash)

**Step 4**

Open Terminal and enter:  `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

**Step 5**

Open Xcode and the bug should be solved!

Comment: @MaximFirsoff Strange. I'll have another look into it. Did you manage ti fix it?